# why can't package in Idea J springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am try use mvn package command in Idea J.
But the result is the  application start runinng.
I want get the Jar in target path.

what should I do?
[image]

Comment: Is there an exception in your test cases? If so, you can always issue `mvn clean package -DskipTests` (though this is not recommended). This does not look like an issue with Intelij itself

Comment: Yes,The command can resolve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cd the project dir.
use the follow command can resolve the question.

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```